# Git Smart HTTP protocol fails to execute server side hooks on push

Tags: git, apache, http, version-control, git-http-backend

I'm trying to set up smart HTTP using git-http-backend. I tried to follow plenty of documentation/guides online on how to do this. I'm running Apache 2.4 on Windows 7. In my httpd.conf I have

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT c:/repos
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL

ScriptAlias /git/ "c:/program files/git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"

<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git.*$">
    Require all granted
</LocationMatch>

<Directory "c:/program files/git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/">
    <Files "git-http-backend.exe">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

For `C:\repos`, I made sure that Everyone has full access. I'm running httpd.exe under my user account so requests made to the server should see git 2.12.2 just fine on the PATH.

In `C:\repos`, I have a bare repo called `foo.git`. Inside that repo I do `git config http.receivepack true`. I was able to clone just fine with http://localhost/git/foo.git. *With no server side hooks enabled*, I was able to push a commit just fine.

Now the annoying part -- I create an update hook which is just `C:\repos\foo.git\hooks\update` that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
exit 0
```

I try pushing from the local repo and get

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 315.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://localhost/git/foo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://localhost/git/foo.git'
```

Ok, so I try pushing the same thing with the git protocol -- I run `git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path=C:\repos C:\repos`. Then I put a `git-daemon-export-ok` inside `foo.git`. I go back to the local repo and push to `git:///foo.git`:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 35.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: foo
To git:///foo.git
   3b33593..6af841c  master -> master
```

Everything goes okay. I push with the file protocol -- `file:///c/repos/foo.git` and that works okay too.

I tried doing a

```
<Directory c:/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in my httpd.conf to make sure it had nothing to do with access issues. I switched this back to `Require all denied` of course.

Based on a verbose push, seems like git-receive-pack can't start the bash interpreter on the server-side, but I'm not sure why. Again, it's spawning from an httpd.exe that's running under my user account and I can execute git just fine manually. And again, git can be found on the PATH just fine. What kind of obvious solution am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my httpd.conf file. Additionally I had to do

```
SetEnv PATH "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"
PassEnv USERNAME
```

First, the `SetEnv` was necessary b.c. the interpreter wasn't being invoked. In one of my hooks, I have a shebang line of `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, thus the addition of `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`. In another hook, I could have `#!/bin/bash`, so `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` would be necessary.

Secondly, the reason for `PassEnv USERNAME` was because one of the hooks was utilizing that environment variable which httpd excludes out when passing an environment to the CGI script. It's talked about in [the Apache docs here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html)